# Перебор массива и вывод ключа

Tags: javascript

Есть select с записанными значениями из массива.Нужно с помощью перебора вывести в какой части массива находится значение select. То-есть если select = "Академгородок" то при нажатии кнопки должно появится red.

```js
const metro = {
 "red" : [
   'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
   ],
 "blue" : [
   'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
 ],
 "green" : [
   'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
    ]
}

let selLine = document.querySelector('#selectLine');
let btnLine = document.querySelector('.btnLine');
let outSecond = document.querySelector('.outSecond');

let massKey = Object.keys(metro);
let massVal = Object.values(metro);

for(let i = 0; i < massVal.length; i++) {
 let val = massVal[i];
 for(let j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
  selLine.add(new Option(val[j]));
 }
}       

btnLine.addEventListener('click', function() {
   let val = selLine.value;
   for(let key in massVal) {
    document.write(val[key])
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectLine"></select>
<button class="btnLine">Push</button>
<div class="outSecond"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const metro = {
 "red" : [
   'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
   ],
 "blue" : [
   'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
 ],
 "green" : [
   'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
    ]
}

let selLine = document.querySelector('#selectLine');
let btnLine = document.querySelector('.btnLine');
let outSecond = document.querySelector('.outSecond');

let massKey = Object.keys(metro);
let massVal = Object.values(metro);

for(let i = 0; i < massVal.length; i++) {
 let val = massVal[i];
 for(let j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
  selLine.add(new Option(val[j]));
 }
}       

btnLine.addEventListener('click', function() {
   let val = selLine.value;
   for(let i = 0; i < massKey.length; i++) { //начиная с этого места
    if(metro[massKey[i]].indexOf(val) >= 0) {
   outSecond.textContent = massKey[i];
  }
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectLine"></select>
<button class="btnLine">Push</button>
<div class="outSecond"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
    red: [
        'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки'
    ],
    blue: [
        'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна'
    ],
    green: [
        'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская'
    ]
};

const selector = document.querySelector('select#selector');

for (const value of Object.values(data))
    for (const option_text of value)
        selector.add(new Option(option_text));

const button = document.querySelector('button#selector-ok');
const out = document.querySelector('span#selector-out');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const key in data) {
        const array = data[key];
        if (array.indexOf(selector.value) !== -1)
            return out.textContent = key;
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="selector"></select>
<button id="selector-ok">OK</button>

<span id="selector-out"></span>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, однако @AlexDevTime уже дал похожий ответ. Мой интернет решил _позабавиться_, поэтому я не сразу заметил, что уже есть симметричное решение.

Comment: Да, но ты постарался переделать весь код, а я поправил только нужное место. Я бы твой вариант выбрал ))) Лайкнул.